# EC2 connectivity with EBS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I am new to AWS this might sound like a weird question.My question is when I try to create a new EBS volume and try to attach it with running EC2 instance,The connectivity between two(EC2 instance --> EBS volumes) is over Public IP or that connectivity is using Private IP.I understand that EBS provides just a block level storage but I want to understand how EC2 instance is going to access that storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods by which an EBS volume is connected to your instance are completely transparent to you. The storage appears on your EC2 instance as an additional block storage device. Amazon maintains a separate back-end storage and management network that is used for this type of traffic.